# Changing order in viewholder

Tags: android, android-viewholder

I have layout of ImageView and TextView and depending on boolean value in java code I'd like image to be on left or right side of text. 
I've found similar problem where removing and adding view at specific index was proposed, but problem is I'm using LayoutInflater and ViewHolder.

What would be better solution: to add two images and depending on boolean value show only one of them or manipulate ViewHolder? If second option - how to do it?

Comment: you can use `RecyclerView` with different `viewType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KingfisherPhuoc suggested you can use `RecyclerView` or create two layouts one with the `ImageView` on left and the other with `ImageView` on right and depending upon the boolean value inflate the corresponding layout.

Or add two `LinearLayouts` in your existing layout one with the `ImageView` on left and the other with `Imageview` on right. And depending upon the boolean value show/hide the respective `LinearLayouts`.

Comment: I went for two ImageViews and setting on one of them `setVisibility(View.GONE)`